# Is the "representation theorems" tag necessary?

Tags: discussion, tagging

A couple of my recent questions have been on representation theory of locally compact groups and when tagging my post, I found this strange tag called [representation-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/representation-theorems). It's only been used by one question and I don't anticipate it being used much in the future (if at all). Should this tag be removed?

Comment: Just for the record, this tag was also discussed [in this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/winter-tag-cleanup/12528#12528). There was [only this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/633425/revisions) in this tag when it was removed.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see relevant things in search but maybe I didn't look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the tag is not informative. Knowing that something is tagged representation-theorems gives me no clue to what the question is about. Representing things by other things happens all over mathematics.  I suggest retagging the question that causes the tag to exist; then the tag will be automatically removed.